# Not able to iterate over java collection in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to iterate a javascript collection of objects in jquery.
when i place an alert I am able to see the collection getting printed but I am not able to iterate over the elements of that collection in jquery. How can I do that?
I tried:

```
    ${mergedConfirmedTechnologies}.each(function(index,element){
    alert("here "+element.product); 
    });
```

but it did not work though when I do:

```
    alert(${mergedConfirmedTechnologies});
```

then it prints the collection of objects
Could anyone suggest how can I iterate over the collection in jquery?

Comment: How do you serialize the collection to JavaScript?

Comment: @MarounMaroun: I think cat and catfish is a better analogy, but Java is actually relevant in this case.

Comment: What exactly does the `alert()` call print?

Comment: Just curious, what is this syntax '${mergedConfirmedTechnologies}'?

Comment: what's inside `mergedConfirmedTechnologies` and which type is it ? I think the question is missing some relevant code

Answer (score 0):

Your example is doing loop in DOM elements of page. You have to user JS loop, not jQuery one.
For example:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < mergedConfirmedTechnologies.lenght; i++)
 {
     alert(mergedConfirmedTechnologies[i]);
 }
```

EDIT: fixed alert() typo

Comment: Oops.. it must be like     alert(mergedConfirmedTechnologies[i]);

Comment: @ShubhDasgupta wrong way going about doing it. Unless the user is willing to change there answer to be correct this answer would be wrong and should have been downvoted and left with a comment. It isn't good to go about editing code in answers.

Comment: @Popeye:- Extremely sorry for that, How do i revert? I am searching that option , the moment i clicked Submit :(

Comment: @Popeye:- I realized that accidentally i edited it, in place of replying it. I replied as comment, and started looking for option to revert. I'll really appreciate if you can help me out.. I can still see my Updated Answer. That is Bugging me a lott.

Comment: @ShubhDasgupta You have to go on edit, than at the top there will be a list of edits that have already been perform on the question/Answer.

Comment: @Popeye:- Man.. Thanks a lott.. I refreshed the page, and i can see it now.. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over the Java collection in Javascript, you first need to convert it into object which Javascript can understand. You can do the following:

1- Convert the Java Collection to a JSON String or directly write the Collection, using EL to the Javascript String.

2- Parse the String to form a Javascript array object.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `forEach`  in jstl and then you can push that into a array in javascript

```
<script>
<c:forEach items="${mergedConfirmedTechnologies}" var="item">
    alert(${item.product});
</c:forEach>
</script>
```

For using `JSTL` tags use the following import statement

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Comment: @user719950 did you check my answer

Comment: @user719950 you can place jstl tag directly in script rag